# Create list of column?

Tags: gwt

I've just learn the MVP architecture from `GWT` offical site, and now I want to develop my application using CellTable. But i stuck at add column definitions part. How do I create an arraylist instances of column interface (used for celltable). I tried but i can only specific the row type, the column type is dynamic, like

```
ArrayList<Column<CategoryClient, C>>
```

So the debugger keep saying that C cant be resolve to a type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following method to acheive your requirement.

```
private <C> Column<CategoryClient, C> addColumn(Cell<C> cell, String headerText,
      final GetValue<C> getter, FieldUpdater<CategoryClient, C> fieldUpdater) {
    Column<CategoryClient, C> column = new Column<CategoryClient, C>(cell) {
      @Override
      public C getValue(ContactInfo object) {
        return getter.getValue(object);
      }
    };
    column.setFieldUpdater(fieldUpdater);
    if (cell instanceof AbstractEditableCell<?, ?>) {
      editableCells.add((AbstractEditableCell<?, ?>) cell);
    }
    contactList.addColumn(column, headerText);
    return column;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. I think i will try it later. I decided to get rid of the <T> part :)